# PHP adding count to function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building a new site in woo/ WordPress and a little stuck, basically the client wants to be able to add custom fields to the checkout (done) but they need to be in a repeatable field so the customer can add the field as many times as they need (done) but I am stuck on the actual integration into the database.

My code is at http://pastebin.com/vR4GWV7w

Basically I need to add a custom ID to each repeatable field input e.g.

child_name1

child_name2

If I was doing this in a template file I would use PHP count but this needs to work in the code below which creates the field.

```
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
 echo '<div id="entry1" class="clonedInput"><h2>' . __('Child Details') . '</h2>';
 woocommerce_form_field( 'child_name', array(
  'type' => 'text',
  'class' => array('child_field form-row-wide'),
  'label' => __('Child Name'),
  'placeholder' => __('Enter the child\'s name'),
 ), $checkout->get_value( 'child_name' ));
}
```

Any help / guidance would be much appreciated, I posted this on the WordPress exchange and got put on hold so trying here as it's a PHP question

Comment: Do you just need ID with any random number or you need order like child_name1, child_name2 etc

Comment: The idea is basically very simple. Just create a session variable and increase the session value in your function my_custom_checkout_field($checkout). Then replace the session value with 'child_name'.

Comment: @RajivRisi I need them to be in the order e.g. child1, child2 as it needs to be added to the database calls further down.

Comment: @RajivRisi can you point me in the direction of how to do this?